# How is Magento sending emails by default?

Tags: email

I noticed when making a customer account on my development server Magento sent a confirmation email from (literally) "owner@example.com" - unsurprisingly, I don't own this domain.

How did this happen as I would have thought there would be steps required before Magento would send emails? More broadly, how does Magento send emails? Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magneto 2 comes up with default E-mail setup after installation you have to setup valid email addresses, each must be set up as a valid email  address for your domain.

You can setup your email address instead of "owner@example.com". Follow below steps.

1. Login to your Magneto 2 store Admin panel On the Admin sidebar, tap Stores and then there will have a flyout menu.  You can see under Settings, choose Configuration.
2. In the panel on the left under General, choose Store Email Addresses.
3. Here you can see all the email address including Sales, Marketing, Support etc..
4. In the Sender Name field, type the name of the person to appear as the sender 
   of any email messages that is associated with the General Contact identity.
5. n the Sender Email field, type the associated email address.
6. When complete, tap Save Config  to apply your Magento 2 email setting.